# Jasmin NoSuchMethodError when converting to binary Java class

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm, jasmin

I am trying to use Jasmin to convert Jasmin assembly code to a Java class file. Using the Hello World example from [here](http://jasmin.sourceforge.net/about.html).

The following error is returned:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: jasmin.parser.parse()V
    at jasmin.ClassFile.readJasmin(ClassFile.java:1160)
    at jasmin.Main.assemble(Main.java:81)
    at jasmin.Main.run(Main.java:200)
    at jasmin.Main.main(Main.java:157)
```

I suspect that it may be a problem with the Java version since Jasmin seems to be old and probably implemented using an older Java version.

So far I have tried to run the example using this command: `java -jar jasmin.jar test.j`.

I have tried to run it with Java 8, 7, 6 and 4 unsuccessfully.

The version of Jasmin I have used is 2.4.

Furthermore I have also tried to download Jasmin's source code and compile it manually, with the same result.

Does anybody have any pointers or ideas on how to solve this issue?

Comment: no: it works without problem

Comment: @Maurice Perry. Do you mind saying which Jasmin version, Java version and OS you're using?

Comment: In version 2.4 the file `parser.java` doesn't have a call to `jasmin.myparser.parse` (line 29 is in the middle of a map definition). Are you sure you are using the right jar?

Comment: @MargaretBloom sorry, that was from the jasmin.jar I compiled and added some debug. I have changed the error trace to the one I obtain from the version 2.4 of jasmin.

Comment: Is it possible that you have an older version of java_cup.parser in the classpath? If you run jasmin with the java option `-verbose` and grep the output for "parser", does the class comes from the jasmin jar?

Comment: @FelipeSulser 2.4 on Windows 10

Comment: @MargaretBloom, that was indeed the issue. I had a different version of java_cup in the classpath. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that, if you have other versions of cup in Java's classpath, jasmin might run intro troubles and it will throw a `NoSuchMethodError`.

To fix this, just remove the other CUP versions from Java's classpath.

All credit goes to @MargaretBloom for finding the issue.